# How to get value of parameter in http post reply using Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, http

Is there a method in Qt that let you search for a key and get the corresponding value in a HTTP GET/POST request reply?

I feel that this is something that surely is available somewhere in the framework, but I can not seem to find it and when searching online I only find topics related to how to send parameters with GET / POST.

Comment: This seems to be an alternative solution, but not exactly what I am looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893525/how-can-we-parse-http-response-header-fields-using-qt-c

Comment: If you use JSON you can check QJSonObject to parse key/value pairs.